# GAC Scope: why does it override local assemblies, and is there anything we can do about it?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, gac

I've spent some time struggling with the GAC today, as a result of it superceding the local assembly in my application directory, and I thought it was odd that the GAC would "rank" a local file; in almost all development cases, the local scope supercedes the global scope.

Why does it do this?  It seems to be counterintuitive.  How do I get around the issue if I have multiple builds of the same assembly (but with different tokens) and I want to use the one that is NOT in the GAC?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use specific version of referenced assembly, set "Specific version" to True in Property editor of Visual Studio for this referenced assembly selected.

If you set it to false it VS should first search in local folder near exe file, unless GAC version of assembly was loaded before by other loaded assemblies as a strongly typed dependency.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems different rules apply to strongly-named assemblies of different public tokens.